# How does Android maintain the linkage info between R constant and the actual file?

Tags: android, android-resources

How does Android maintain the linkage info between R constant and the actual resource file?

For example,

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity);
```

R.layout.activity points to res/layout/activity.xml. R.layout.activity is stored in the R.java file, but where is this linkage info maintained?

Comment: ... in the `R.Java` file. There are defined all the constants associated to the resources. For instance, `layout` is a Class in R.Java, which contains all the integer constants associated to the layout components. It's easier for you to open the R.Java file and see what's inside it (really, it's a trivial task to understand its contents). But please don't alter it manually.

Comment: Thanks - I know the constant is defined in there, but I would like to know where it stores the linkage between the constant and the actual resource xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The `R` class is generated by the *aapt* tool as can be seen in the header of the file *R.java*:

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */
```

You can find the file in Android Studio by selecting an *R* symbol in your code and then selecting menu item *Navigate | Declaration*. The aapt tool is automatically run in the build process and also in response to file changes in the resources dir in order to give you up to date source code symbols.

If you mean to ask where the mapping between the constants for the layout files and the filenames is stored then I don't know if there is such a mapping. The *aapt* does more than just generate the R class. It also packages all those resources together. I expect that it packages them by resource Id and not by original filename.

Comment: Yes I would like to know the mapping or how Android knows to map the constant to the resource.

Comment: I think it doesn't map the constant R.layout.activity to /res/layout/activity.xml, but to an internal structure of the package it builds. So there is no such mapping.

Comment: Also remember that R.layout.activity does not represent a single xml file, but a set of files in different dirs, e.g.: res/layout/, res/layout-land/, res/layout-v21/, etc.